# cakephp routing not working

Tags: php, cakephp

*routes.php* file

```
Router::connect('/:id',array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

*postscontroller*

```
function view()

public function view($id){

if(!$id){
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry Invalid id.'));
}
$post=$this->Post->findById($id);
if(!$post){
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry Invalid id.'));
     return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
}
$this->set('post',$post);
}
```

Link form index I'm calling

```
<td> 
<?php echo $this->Html->link($row['Post']['title'],array('action'=>'view',$row['Post']['id']));?>
</td>
```

But routing is not working. Please help anyone.

Comment: Did you place that **before** the standard routing?

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting `/:id`, but your link is pointing to `/view/:id`.